# Issue with plotting numpy array in 3D after computing stl data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
 T,_,_ = bestFit(stlA.normals, src[:m,:].T)

    figure = pyplot.figure()
    axes = mplot3d.Axes3D(figure)
    axes.add_collection3d(mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(T,_,_.vectors))
    scale = T,_,_.flatten('C')
    axes.auto_scale_xyz(scale,scale,scale)
    pyplot.show()
```

I'm having issues getting a 3d plot to work for a numpy array. I've been trying to find the best fit curve on two STL files using iterative closest point and this part of my code is throwing this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "C:/Users/Dad Christie/Documents/Capstone/icpV2.py", line 102, in <module>
> >           main()
> >       File "C:/Users/Dad Christie/Documents/Capstone/icpV2.py", line 98, in main
> >           axes.add_collection3d(mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(T,_,_.vectors))
> >     
> >     **AttributeError**: `numpy.ndarray` object has no attribute `vectors`

Here is the full code

```
#Needed imports
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib import pyplot

#Create best fit function. This will create a best fit curve
#to superimpose the images onto
def bestFit(arrayA, arrayB):

    m = arrayA.shape[1]

    #Create centroids along horizontal axis - translate points
    centroidA = np.mean(arrayA, axis = 0)
    centroidB = np.mean(arrayB, axis = 0)
    #print (CentroidA)
    subA = arrayA - centroidA
    subB = arrayB - centroidB

    #Create the rotation matrix
    rotH = np.dot(subA.T, subB)
    rotU, rotS, rotVt = np.linalg.svd(rotH)
    rotR = np.dot(rotVt.T, rotU.T)

    #Reflection Case
    if np.linalg.det(rotR) < 0:
        rotVt[m-1,:] *= -1
        rotR = np.dot(rotVt.T, rotU.T)

    #Create translation
    translate = centroidB.T - np.dot(rotR, centroidA.T)

    #transformation
    T = np.identity(m+1)
    T[:m, :m] = rotR
    T[:m, m] = translate

    return T, rotR, translate

def NearestNeighbor(src, dst):
    neigh = NearestNeighbors(1)
    neigh.fit(dst)
    distances, indices = neigh.kneighbors(src, return_distance = True)
    return distances.ravel(), indices.ravel()

def main():

    initPose = None
    maxIterations = 20
    tolerance = 0.001

    #Load in the images with
    #numpy STL
    stlA = mesh.Mesh.from_file('Images/lowerArch00.stl')
    stlB = mesh.Mesh.from_file('Images/lowerArch06.stl')
    #print (stlA.vectors)

    m = stlA.normals.shape[1]

    #Make points homogenous and copy them
    src = np.ones((m+1, stlA.normals.shape[0]))
    dst = np.ones((m+1, stlB.normals.shape[0]))
    src[:m,:] = np.copy(stlA.normals.T)
    dst[:m,:] = np.copy(stlB.normals.T)

    #Initial pose estimation
    if initPose is not None:
        src = np.dot(initPose, src)

    error = 0

    for i in range(maxIterations):
        #Find nearest neighbors between current and destination
        distances, indices = NearestNeighbor(src[:m, :].T, dst[:m, :].T)

        #Compute the transformation
        T,_,_ = bestFit(src[:m,:].T, dst[:m,indices].T)

        #update source
        src = np.dot(T,src)

        #error check
        meanError = np.mean(distances)
        if np.abs(error - meanError) < tolerance:
            break
        error = meanError

    #calculate final transformation
    T,_,_ = bestFit(stlA.normals, src[:m,:].T)

    figure = pyplot.figure()
    axes = mplot3d.Axes3D(figure)
    axes.add_collection3d(mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(T,_,_.vectors))
    scale = T,_,_.flatten('C')
    axes.auto_scale_xyz(scale,scale,scale)
    pyplot.show()
main()
```

Comment: `bestFit` returns three `np.ndarray` objects. What are you expecting to get when you do `T, _, _.vectors`? That is attempting to access `np.ndarray.vectors` which [doesn't exist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) - hence the attribute error

Comment: For the most part, I'm trying to see the data so I can better understand how the array is being created and is arranged in 3D space. Im assuming I have to take the best fit ndarrays and create a mesh that enables me to access these vectors? Or is there a way to represent the arrays in a 3D space without having to rely on a mesh? Most of this code has mostly been about finding out what data I'm able to access from these stl files. For this issue, I've mostly been trying to visually see what data that Im manipulating with the ICP function. If not, then I will most likely 2d plot bestFit

Comment: that depends what you mean by vectors, if you want to represent a set of points defined as vectors you can use a scatter plot, if you want to represent vectors as arrows/quivers you can use a quiverplot. But my first comment was trying to get at what you are expecting `_.vectors` to give you?

Comment: O, I see, I was hoping for a vector of points. The 3D meshes I am using are using can be plotted with these vectors. Since they both rely on numpy arrays, I was hoping for a similar result.

Comment: What does `print(_.shape)` give you?

Comment: Shape comes out as (3,). Edit: So Im only getting a single vector of size 3 then?

Comment: Yes, it would appear so - which does make sense given that you appear to be calculating a transformation matrix of some sort and accessing only a specific column of it

Comment: Okay I see, I appreciate the help! Ill see what I can figure out from here

Comment: No problem, best of luck